# Can we use multiple synchronization block in the same method

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm using executor framework for multi-threading and have some confusion regarding synchronization block execution. Can anybody suggest that if following code have issue regarding synchronization and if yes how I can improve this? Thanks.

```
public class ProcessDemo {

    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    @SuppressWarnings("InfiniteLoopStatement")
    public void startProcess(){

        do {
            // making connection with clients
            ThreadingDemo thread = new ThreadingDemo(clientDemo);
            executorService.execute(thread);
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

```
public class ThreadingDemo implements Runnable{

    private ClientDemo clientDemo;

    ThreadingDemo(ClientDemo clientDemo){
        this.clientDemo = clientDemo;
    }
    public void run(){
        if(someCodition){
            synchronized (ThreadingDemo.class){
                clientDemo.show();
            }
        }

        synchronized (ThreadingDemo.class){
            myMethod1();
        }
    }

    private void myMethod1() {
        clientDemo.start();
        clientDemo.show();
    }
}
```

```
public class ClientDemo {

    void start(){

    }
    void show(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is - you are trying to acquire class level lock and only one thread can execute at a time. I am not sure about your requirement but if you want a concurrent execution then you should you use object level lock.

Comment: Thanks @Hiccup. If only one thread is executing then I'm OK with that and it actually my requirement. In my application multiple objects of ClientDemo will be there and according to following description(link) one instance of the class can be acquired  by only one thread(if we are using class level lock)
[link](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/multi-threading/object-vs-class-level-locking/)

Comment: Do I need to make the clientDemo data member final in ThreadingDemo class?

Comment: It does not make any difference as  ClientDemo class does not have any instance variable.

Comment: @Feku279 i did not understand the need of synchronized use inside Runnable. Can you share what you are trying to achieve with this.